# angularjs input text focus is working in desktop not working for iPad

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a search input box in my application. Whenever i will click button, search input will get open. But it is not autofocusing.

Please lookt at my code,

```js
$scope.goSearch = function () {
   $scope.$broadcast("focusTextInput");
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link-img search-icon" ui-sref="search" ng-click="goSearch();"><img src="assets/images/searchIconDefault.svg"/></a>

<input type="search" autofocus class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search Card" ng-model="search"  focus-on="focusTextInput">
```

```js
 app.directive("focusOn", function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on(attrs.focusOn, function (e) {
          $timeout((function () {
            element[0].focus();
          }), 10);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

This is the code i am using.

- ) The only problem is, cursor blinking focus is working in Desktop, laptop but it is not working in ipad and ipad pro.

Can you please tell how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below example

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.goSearch = function() {
    document.getElementById("search").focus();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<a class="nav-link-img search-icon" ui-sref="search" ng-click="goSearch();">&#128269;</a>

<input type="search" autofocus id="search" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search Card" ng-model="search"  focus-on="focusTextInput">

</div>
```

Comment: Did you add `id="search"` in your input box?

Comment: yes i added. But still focus is not working only in ipad and ipad pro. If i click on textbox it is working. But I want on page load.

Comment: It seems we don't have another option.